# Recover ASP.NET MVC Project From Files Stored On IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Ok so I did the idiot thing and I think I deleted my folder that had a visual studio mvc project. One good thing is I already published it to an IIS site.

Now my question is, how can I recover the project using the files on the IIS server? I can see the views, etc. but I don't appear to see any controller files, etc.

I've seen some other answers for older versions of asp.net where you could decompile to get your code behind back. MVC doesn't have code behind so how can I do this?

Please help me.

Comment: This is for old asp.net anything like this for new?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421401/recover-asp-net-project-from-iis-deployment

Comment: **YOU DID NOT USE A SOURCE CONTROL ??? A SOURCE CONTROL???**

Comment: I use VSTS and source tree but alas before I could add it to source it's gone :(

Comment: Let this be a lesson: never ever write code without having it be source controlled, and that code should be on at least two machines at a time so that you have a backup.

Comment: So you deployed code without that code having been committed to your source control?

Comment: Please read the prev comment in ross gellers voice https://imgur.com/a/tHbWz

Comment: You can still decompile the DLL to get the source code back: but it's likely going to look different from the original code.

Comment: I don't know whats worse the hot coffee that i just had poured on my face accidentally or losing a project that had some stuff that was tricky to code. ugh :(

Thanks for all the answers I think im sol and will just have to fix my workflow to avoid this again in the future

Comment: You say there's no code behind, but that's not exactly true. Your project is compiled into a dll and that dll is stored in the bin directory. This is the same as the code behind sections of webforms projects. You will need to decompile the dll to get the code, and then all the razor views etc for the views

Comment: Ah so that is where the code is stored thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller classes are compiled into binaries when you build and publish into IIS. You can go to your IIS bin folder, find the compiled web .ddl and then use some tools to view the source (try ILspy)

Comment: Thank you I ended up using redgate's software to look into the dll's. I was able to find what i needed. Thanks!

Comment: always glad to help!

Comment: How to find controller folder.